# My ip becomes localhost when accesing XAMMP directory remotely

Tags: apache, xampp, remote-access, moodle, httpd.conf

I'm working on a local installation of Moodle using XAMMP. I need a coworker (we are both connected to the same LAN) to change some settings; she sees the main dashboard when she inputs my ip (which means, she already has access to my XAMMP directory), the problem is whenever she inputs

```
{my_ip}/moodle/
```

in the browser, {my_ip} turns to localhost

```
localhost/moodle/
```

which obviously outcomes ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED as a result.

How can I prevent this? How can I give her permission to see the /moodle/ directory remotely?

Answer (score 0):

Change the $CFG->wwwroot variable in your config.php file, as it is currently pointing to "localhost/moodle", so when she loads your site, that is the URL it redirects to.